# Google Maps v3: Markerclusterer not being fired?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bit of a puzzle on my hands. I'm Using Google Maps v3 and MarkerClusterer v3. When I load my page, the map appears, the points are all there, but nothing is clustered.

If I go to the firebug console and do:

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

Suddenly clustering works.

Weirdly, If I put an alert between the map instantiation and the markerclusterer instantiation, again clustering suddenly works. 
Here is the end of my $(document).ready function:

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

and all it takes to make the clustering work is:

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    alert("test");
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to refresh the map somehow? Is that what is happening with the alert box?

If you need more code drop me a comment.

Comment: Can you post a little more code?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?  I'm having the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I posted my code for you bro. If you have more questions leave a comment. I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a lightly edited version of what I ended up using. I'm giving most of script here so people can get an idea of the context each function is happening in as well as the scope of everything. Hopefully this will save someone some head scratching.

```
var initialize = function(){

    var markers = [];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    function load_content(marker, id){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'eventos/' + id,
            success: function(data){
                infowindow.setContent(data);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        });
    }

    var opt = { ...options...}

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), opt);

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(-44.4419, 170.1419));
    map.setZoom(9);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'eventos/',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){

            $.each(data, function(i, a){

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(a.evento.lat, a.evento.lng);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position : latlng,
                    title: a.evento.title
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'closeclick', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent("");
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

                    infowindow.close();

                    infowindow.setContent("<img src='loading.gif'>");

                    load_content(marker, a.evento.id);
                });

                markers.push(marker);
            });

            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

        }

    });

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem comes from the fact that `$.ajax()`, `$.getJSON()` are asynchronous methods. Once executed, your code is not blocked (otherwise the browser would be blocked as well). Therefore, `var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);` is called before the end of the AJAX response processing. 
To solve this issue, you have to use a callback, such as `complete()`, which is fired once the processing is done.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('/your_data.json', function(data) {
  for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    // code to display markers
  }
}).complete(function() { 
  var marker_cluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and symptoms. My solution in the end was to load the map with google loader instead, which for some reason worked fine.

This does not work with mapclusterer:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
...
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
```

While this works:

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
...
google.load('maps', '3', { other_params: 'sensor=false' });
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

function initalize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}
```

This workaround might not be possible for everyone, but hopefully someone can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this [thread on MarkerClusterer v3](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/142dbdf66a94a133)? It's got a few links to some handy resources, namely code examples and reference docs.

Check the examples and make sure they're working OK in your testing browser (you never know, could be an issue with MC).

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at that thread. The examples all work fine and according to the docs I am doing the right thing. I must be doing the right thing because it works sometimes. If only I can get it to work all the time...

Comment: Definitely using MarkerClusterer v3 in your project? Could you post a little more code, see if we can fix this thang!